# How do I create an alias for the server name?

Tags: linux

The naming convention chosen for the servers I work with gives me names that are too close: dnb, dnp, dna. I want to rename them, see something like 'betaTest' instead of dnb when I log into dnb to work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That depends on the programs you want to use to access them and on the administrative rights you have,

Comment: Is "log in" just ssh (you can define names in `~/.ssh/config`), or also database connections, web frontends, etc (you might want to edit `/etc/hosts`)?

Comment: I love this resource that describes how to really get the information you need: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. You haven't said *where* you'd like to see this name. On the command line? In your terminal application? Something else? Assuming you mean on the command line:

You could edit the .bashrc file in your home directory to replace the hostname with something more useful to you. Run these commands:

```
touch ~/.bashrc
echo 'PS1=${PS1//\\[hH]/usefulname}' >> .bashrc
```

The first line is just to make sure you have a .bashrc file. If you don't, it will create an empty one. The second line will add everything between the single quotes to the end of your .bashrc file. $PS1 is a variable that is printed out every time a command returns. It's the prompt. (You could try echoing out $PS1 before you do this, to see what it looks like beforehand.) This line, once added to your .bashrc file, will just take what your prompt already was, but replace the hostname part of it with whatever name is more useful to you. Be sure to replace "usefulname" with whatever you want it to be on that server. Then run these on each server where you want the name changed to something else.

This will not change the actual hostname of your servers, only what's displayed to you when you log in. And if you ever want to undo this, you can open the .bashrc file and simply remove this line. It won't affect anything else. Anything else that needs to know the server's name will keep using the "dnb" or "dnp" or whatever it actually is, both before and after this change.

Bonus information: The new value being assigned to PS1 is using the shell's parameter expansion feature. (This works on bash, ksh, and zsh.) It's saying "take the current value of this variable, PS1, and replace all occurences of a backslash followed by an upper or lowercase "h", and replace it with usefulname". Since a backslash followed by an h or an H is the prompt's code to show the hostname, this will result in replacing the hostname with "usefulname" in your prompt.